# How can I make an armature for eyes?

Tags: bones, parent

I am struggling with setting bones of eyes in a model. I followed some eye riggings tutorials and applied it on my model.

I can change the direction of eyes with IK's. And when i rotate my model's head, eyes follow the position properly. However when i move another bone like hip bones, eyes moves non-propotional to head. They move fastly. How can I arrange that?

Here is what i did:

i added two bones to both of eyes. and added their IK's. Then i connected the eyes ('n object mode) to bones (in pose mode) with bone choice. Lastly i connected both bones of eyes to head bone with keeping offset.

Comment: I would advise to post a picture of the armature and the panel where you have the IK.

Answer (score 1):

okay i solved the issue. i deselect vertex groups of eyes in armature section at modifier tab. know eyes move as they should be. maybe this helps others who struggle with same problem.

Comment: Please add more detail to your answer, so it is useful to users in the future.